# I want to use bubblesort on a text file to sort a set of randomised numbers

Tags: c#, file, bubble-sort

I'm trying to use bubblesort on a text file with many different numbers. So far, I've nailed the part where the numbers from the text file are read, but I'm struggling with the part where I use bubblesort to arrange the numbers.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class Trial
{
    public static void Main(string[]args)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        // point to where our file actually is
        string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        string filePath = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "a2_task1_input1.txt");
        Console.WriteLine(filePath); // This line reveals the filepath
        LinkedList<int> list = new LinkedList<int>();

        // read the file
        string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        Console.WriteLine(fileContents); // This line reveals the contents of the file


        stopwatch.Start(); // Stopwatch begins
        // process the contents of the file

        string[] numbers = fileContents.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string number in numbers)
        {
            int value = int.Parse(number); // The int.parse converts these into numbers
            list.AddLast(value);
        }
        

// I want to integrate the bottom lines of code into the part above. But instead of the numbers in the array, I want those in the text file

         int[] array = { 2, 4, 1, 3, 8, 6, 9, 7, 5 }; 
          BubbleSort(array);
          foreach (int number in array)
          {
              Console.Write(number + " ");
          }

/// This is the end bit of the code I want to integrate

        stopwatch.Stop();
        long elapsedTimeMs = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time: " + elapsedTimeMs);



    }


    static void BubbleSort(int[] arr)
    {
        int n = arr.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
            {
                if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
                {
                    // swap operation
                    int temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                    arr[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

The program outputs the unsorted collection of numbers, as well as the sorted numbers in the int [] array. I want to make it where the int[] array contains the numbers from the text file

**Edit 1**: Here is the output in the console

> 70 261 9851 6051 4741 9065 3533 8692 9175 5178 4358 2580
>
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> Elapsed time: 11

**Edit 2**: This is for a school assignment, in which I have to specifically use BubbleSort to sort the data as part of the marking criteria

Comment: You need to convert `list` to an array and pass that to `BubbleSort`. For example: `BubbleSort(list.ToArray());`

Comment: Why do you use a LinkedList? And why BubbleSort? (the framework has built in support for sorting)

Comment: Use a `List<int>` instead and declare the parameter of `BubbleSort` as `IList<int>` because it is compatible with `List<int>` as well as with `int[]`. So you have the choice to pass it a list or an array.

Comment: If this is for a school assignment, be clear about that. The community doesn't mind helping if you show that you have made a good effort and are clear about what you are struggling with, but often school assignments will force you to do things that could be solved much easier ways, so being clear about the assignment requirements help people who are trying to help you.

Comment: @TJRockefeller Sorry about that, this is for a school assignment yes. Even though c# does have built-in sorting, I have to specifically use BubbleSort since it's needed as part of the marking criteria.

Comment: `var numbers = fileContents.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(int.Parse).ToArray();` Then `BubbleSort(numbers);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a `List<int>` instead of a `LinkedList<int>` unless the linked list is some sort of requirement for the assignment. Adding to the `List<int>` would be `list.Add(value)` instead of `list.AddLast(value)`

Once you have your numbers added to a list, then converting it to an array is trivial

```cs
list.ToArray();
```

that array can then be passed into your `BubbleSort` method.